# what does 있을라카지 mean?

Tags: vocabulary

What does the word 있을라카지 mean in the sentence 자신은 언제나 있을라카지 ?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify it, or if you have checked a dictionary, what exactly was the problem. Was this word not available in the dictionary? Was the definition too complicated? As of it's current state, this question has high chances of getting closed or deleted.

Answer (score 4):

The normal Korean form would be 있으려고 하지 - to intend to stay.

있을라 하지 is a more informal spoken form.

있을라카지  is [경상도](https://namu.wiki/w/%EA%B2%BD%EC%83%81%EB%8F%84) pronunciation of 있을라 하지.